# Socket.io emit to everyone in the room except the sender

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I have a chat room, and I want to emit a message to everyone except me (b/c I'm going to update the chat window via JS on form submit with my message), I tried like this:

```
io.sockets.in(socket.room)
          .broadcast
          .emit('new message', {
            'username' : socket.nickname,
            'message' : data,
            'color' : socket.color
          });
```

It doesn't work. Do you guys know how can I do this?

Comment: Should probably be `socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit(...);` by the nice list in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10099325/4879

Answer (score -3):

If you just remove the broadcast, you should sent to everyone, even the sender. The broadcast namespace makes so the message is sent to everyone *except* the sender. Just check the [docs](http://socket.io/docs/#broadcasting-messages). So for example

```
io.sockets.in(socket.room)
      .emit('new message', {
        'username' : socket.nickname,
        'message' : data,
        'color' : socket.color
      });
```

Comment: Yeah but this emits to myself as well, i don't want to see the message...only the other ones that are in the room should see my message