# Sender of Socket.io message cant get messages like other users

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to implement `Socket.io`'s `Room` functionality and my configuration is like this:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.join('123');
    //...
}
```

And when I want to emit an event:

```
socket.in('123').emit('sendMessage', {items:values]});
```

But everyone gets this message except the sender of this message. Why? Do I have to `emit()` a separate message for sender?

If I use `socket.to('123')` instead of `socket.in('123')` I get the same result and nothing changes. I use the `Socket.io`'s official documents:
http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: Here you have a [list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender-socket-io) with the different methods. Try with `io.sockets.in('123').emit('sendMessage', 'your message');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to send to everyone including the sender you need to use the following syntax:

```
io.sockets.in('123').emit('message', 'cool game');
```

note that this is using the **global** io which I would assume you would have included like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
```