# How to emit an event in response to an event using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am new to socket.io, and trying to get it to work. I don't know what I am doing wrong here, as it seems super straightforward - yet it is not working. I suppose I am missing something obvious. Hopefully someone else can see what that is.

I am setting up socket.io to work with a node/express server. Here is a simplified version of the test I am trying to do.

Server:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

/* socket.io test */
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('helloServer', function(clientMessage){
    console.log("Server got 'helloServer' event");
    socket.emit('helloClient', { message : "Hi there. We got your message: " + clientMessage.message});
  });
});
```

The client has a function `callServer` that is called when a user clicks a button in the UI:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');

function callServer() {
  socket.emit('helloServer', { message : "Hello server!" });
}

socket.on('helloClient', function (serverMessage) {
  console.log(serverMessage.message);
});
```

When I run this code, and click the button that calls `callServer`, the server does get the event, `helloServer`, because I see that the console logs the message as expected, but the client never receives a `helloClient` event. It is as if the `socket.emit` call within the `socket.on` response function never gets called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be ok. But, just in case, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender-socket-io) with all ways of sending data to clients and try use "io.emit" (to send to all clients). Or try sending a string instead of a json object.

I have tried this [example here](https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example) and it is working, just copied and pasted.

Comment: Thanks. using `io.emit` worked - though I don't understand why. Apparently,  multiple sockets are being opened. I will need to delve deeper into the documentation. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, maybe that's the problem. To guarantee that you want to reply the sender client, get it's socket id and reply to it direcly using `socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Indeed, more than one socket was being created. The code I posted above was a simplified version of my actual code, which was much longer. I found the bug in the actual code, thanks to your help.