# Nodejs could not send message to online specific soket

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

i'm trying to implement simple push notification based on socket.io, in my simple code to practice how can i do that i wrote simple code, in my code i can't send message to connected user , when use logged into system i store `socket.io` with the key on `redis`, but on send message to user i get key as username from redis and stored `socket.io` value from redis and i'm trying to send, i get the same `socket.io` value but message dont send to user

client side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Document
    </title>
    </meta>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#login').click(function () {
                socket.emit('login', {username: 'a', password: 'a'});
            });

            $('#mesage').click(function () {
                socket.emit('message', 'a');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        var socket = new io.connect('http://192.168.1.35:3000', {
            port      : 3000,
            transports: ['websocket']
        });

        socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log('connected!');
        });

        socket.on('login', function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        });

        socket.on('message', function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        });

        socket.on('hello,', function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        });

        socket.on('success', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h3 id="login">
    login
</h3>

<h3 id="mesage">
    mesage
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

server side:

```
var socket      = require('socket.io'),
    express     = require('express'),
    app         = express(),
    server      = require('http').createServer(app),
    io          = socket.listen(server),
    port        = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    redis       = require("redis"),
    redisClient = redis.createClient();

socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('login', function (data) {
        login(data.username, data.password, function (success, value) {
            if (success) {
                redisClient.exists(data.username, function (err, doesExist) {
                    if (err) return;
                    if (!doesExist) {
                        redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id);
                    }
                    else {
                        redisClient.del(data.username);
                        redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id);
                    }
                    log.info("SOCKET ID: " + socket.id);
                });
                socket.emit('login', {result: success, id: socket.id});
            } else {
                socket.emit('login', {result: false, id: socket.id});
            }
        });
    });
    socket.on('message', function (username) {
        redisClient.get(username, function (err, socketId) {
            if (err)
                socket.emit('message', err);
            io.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');
        });
    });

});
```

when i click on `login` i get this result:

```
 Object { result=true,  id="/#A5sR-Xo-Owo97NvRAAAB"}
```

and when i click on message i get this result:

```
user not connected /#A5sR-Xo-Owo97NvRAAAB
```

both of `socket.id`s are the same, but client dont get any message and server return this message as `user not connected`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in this code:

```
redisClient.get(username, function (err, socketId) {
    if (err)
        socket.emit('message', err);
    io.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');
});
```

Your callback receives `socketId` as the second argument, but you use `socketid` (lowercase) when you send a message.

Also it's better to quit a function when you send an error message:

```
if (err) return socket.emit('message', err);
```

or:

```
if (err) {
    socket.emit('message', err);
    return;
}
```

otherwise you might have unexpected errors.

Hope this helps.