# Socket.io Send to specific socketId not working

Tags: javascript, angular, express, socket.io

I'm using **Socket.Io 1.7.3** on Angular 2 , which connect to **ExpressJS** Server. I can't send the package to the specific socket id, event they are actually match.

**Server implementation**:

```
socket.on('subscribeNotification', function(data){
        // Get new notification by user_id here ....
        console.log('Got notification request');
        console.log('Your Id is: '+socket.id);
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.id).emit('sendNotificationsToUser', {
            text: 'hello',
            id: socket.id
        });
        socket.emit('claimId', {
            id: socket.id
        });
    });
```

And on **Angular 2 Implementation**:

```
subscribeNotificationEvent(userId: string) {
        let socket = this.socket;
        let data = {
            user_id: userId
        };
        // Emit socket
        socket.emit('subscribeNotification', data);
    }
    listenToNotification() {
        let socket = this.socket;
        socket.on('sendNotificationsToUser', function (data) {
            console.log('I hear it !');
        });
        socket.on('claimId', (data) => {
            console.log('My id is: ' + data.id);
        })
    }
```

**Logging Result**

**Server:**

```
Got notification request
Your Id is: bSCHMUL2bJJQCXkxAAAC
```

**Client:**

```
My id is: bSCHMUL2bJJQCXkxAAAC
```

The client doesn't receive `sendNotificationsToUser` event, so it cannot log out the line `'I hear it !'`.

I have also refered to [Sending message to specific client in Socket IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680565/sending-message-to-specific-client-in-socket-io) , but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you use `socket.broadcast.to` (that I do not se documented anywhere) instead of `socket.send`?

Comment: @rpadovani I get it here https://socket.io/docs/server-api/ and also from the post I attached. The example in their official doc: `client.broadcast.to(id).emit('my message', msg);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not receiving the message because you are the sender.

```
socket.broadcast.emit(msg); // Every socket receives the message, but the socket
```

Adding the `toId` doesn't change the fact that the sender ignore the message.

If you want ot send only to the socket, just use `socket.emit`

Comment: Feel like I walked to my door and sent a letter to myself. Thank you.