# socket.io - can't emit data from server to specific client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I'm trying to emit data from server to one specific client upon connecting (this is server code):

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.id = Math.random();

   //this works, but sends data to all clients, which is not what I need
   socket.emit('serverMsg');

   //this seems to do nothing
   io.to(socket.id).emit('serverMsg');

   //this also does nothing
   socket.broadcast.to(socket.id).emit('serverMsg');
});
```

As I've commented the lines, I can emit data to all clients, but nothing happens when I try to emit to specific client with socket.id.
What am I doing wrong? There are no error messages or anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending message to specific client in Socket IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680565/sending-message-to-specific-client-in-socket-io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a client connects, its `socket.id` is automatically initialized. Also, it joins a [room](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room) with the same name:

> Each Socket in Socket.IO is identified by a random, unguessable,
>   unique identifier Socket#id. For your convenience, each socket
>   automatically joins a room identified by this id.

If, for some reason, you wish to redefine the id, you would need to assign the socket to the corresponding room as well, since the `to( )` method expects as its argument the name of the room of interest. In the code in your post, you redefine the `id`, but the association with the corresponding room is not established, thus the `emit` method emits the data into the "void" (into a room the name of which is equal to the result of `Math.random()`, but which contains no sockets)...

```
const customId = ....
socket.id = customId;

socket.join(customId);

io.to(customId).emit(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
const http = require('http').createServer();
const sio = require('socket.io')(http);

var port = xxxx;
var ip = "xxx.xxx.x.x";

sio.on('connection', async function(socket) {
     sio.sockets.to(socket.id).emit("from_server", "your are connected"); 
});



http.listen(port, ip, function() {
    console.log('Server active. listening on :' + ip + ":" + port);
});
```