# How to manage websockets across multiple servers / workers

Tags: python, websocket, python-3.5, channel, aiohttp

[aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) has built-in support for [websockets](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/web.html#websockets). It's very simple and works well.

A simplified version of the example in the docs is:

```
async def handler(request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)

    # Async iterate the messages the client sends
    async for message in ws:
        ws.send_str('You sent: %s' % (message.data,))

    print('websocket connection closed')
```

In the example, `ws` is a reference to a websocket connection with a client. I could easily put this references into `request.app`, like [@Crandel does here](https://github.com/Crandel/aiohttp/blob/fdf8243ae32d24052c40a754d3b22d2141eb3408/chat/views.py#L27) (i.e., global state), but not in a production app, because each app server (and even each worker) will have its own `app` instance.

Is there an accepted pattern for this? Is there another way?

Note: I'm not referring to sessions. I'm referring to connections. I want to send a message to clients that connected to server A when events occur in application code in server B, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update (Feb 2017)

Channels was (fortunately) not merged into Django. It will probably remain a great project, but it didn't really belong in Django proper.

Also, I would highly recommend taking a look at Postgres's relatively new, built-in support for pub/sub. It will [probably outperform anything else](http://blog.sagemath.com/2017/02/09/rethinkdb-vs-postgres.html), and building a custom solution atop aiohttp, using Postgres as the backing service, might be your best bet.

#### Original

Though not aiohttp, [Django Channels](http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which is likely to be merged into [Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/), solves this problem in a very intuitive way, and it's written by [Andrew Godwin](https://github.com/andrewgodwin), the author of Django [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/migrations/).

Django Channels abstracts the notion of "many processes on many servers" by creating a routing layer in front of a Django app. This routing layer speaks with a backend (e.g., Redis) to maintain a sharable state among processes, and uses a new [ASGI](http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/asgi.html) protocol to facilitate handling both HTTP requests and WebSockets, while delegating each to their respective "[consumers](http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#first-consumers)" (e.g., ships with a built-in handler for HTTP requests, and you can write your own for WebSockets).

Django Channels has a concept called [Groups](http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#groups), which handles the "broadcast" nature of the problem; that is to say, it allows an event which occurs on a server to trigger messages to clients that are in that Group, regardless of whether they're connected to the same or different process or server.

IMHO, Django Channels is very likely to be abstracted into a more general Python library. There are a [couple other](https://goless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) [Python libraries](https://chan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that achieve [Go-like Channels](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) but, as of this writing, there is nothing noteworthy that offers network transparency; the ability for Channels to communicate between processes and servers.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to have multiple websocket servers, each with multiple clients connected, but you want to be able to communicate potentially with all of the connected clients.

Here is an example that creates three trivial servers -- a capitalization echo, a random quote, and time of day -- and then sends a broadcast message to all of the connected clients.  Maybe this has some useful ideas in it.

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/xDSACmdV

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Illustrates how to have multiple websocket servers running and send
messages to all their various clients at once.

In response to stackoverflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820782/how-to-manage-websockets-across-multiple-servers-workers

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/xDSACmdV
"""
import asyncio
import datetime
import random
import time
import webbrowser

import aiohttp
from aiohttp import web

__author__ = "Robert Harder"
__email__ = "rob@iharder.net"
__license__ = "Public Domain"


def main():
    # Create servers
    cap_srv = CapitalizeEchoServer(port=9990)
    rnd_srv = RandomQuoteServer(port=9991)
    tim_srv = TimeOfDayServer(port=9992)

    # Queue their start operation
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(cap_srv.start())
    loop.create_task(rnd_srv.start())
    loop.create_task(tim_srv.start())

    # Open web pages to test them
    webtests = [9990, 9991, 9991, 9992, 9992]
    for port in webtests:
        url = "http://www.websocket.org/echo.html?location=ws://localhost:{}".format(port)
        webbrowser.open(url)
    print("Be sure to click 'Connect' on the webpages that just opened.")

    # Queue a simulated broadcast-to-all message
    def _alert_all(msg):
        print("Sending alert:", msg)
        msg_dict = {"alert": msg}
        cap_srv.broadcast_message(msg_dict)
        rnd_srv.broadcast_message(msg_dict)
        tim_srv.broadcast_message(msg_dict)

    loop.call_later(17, _alert_all, "ALL YOUR BASE ARE BELONG TO US")

    # Run event loop
    loop.run_forever()


class MyServer:
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port  # type: int
        self.loop = None  # type: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop
        self.app = None  # type: web.Application
        self.srv = None  # type: asyncio.base_events.Server

    async def start(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.app = web.Application()
        self.app["websockets"] = []  # type: [web.WebSocketResponse]
        self.app.router.add_get("/", self._websocket_handler)
        await self.app.startup()
        handler = self.app.make_handler()
        self.srv = await asyncio.get_event_loop().create_server(handler, port=self.port)
        print("{} listening on port {}".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.port))

    async def close(self):
        assert self.loop is asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.srv.close()
        await self.srv.wait_closed()

        for ws in self.app["websockets"]:  # type: web.WebSocketResponse
            await ws.close(code=aiohttp.WSCloseCode.GOING_AWAY, message='Server shutdown')

        await self.app.shutdown()
        await self.app.cleanup()

    async def _websocket_handler(self, request):
        assert self.loop is asyncio.get_event_loop()
        ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
        await ws.prepare(request)
        self.app["websockets"].append(ws)

        await self.do_websocket(ws)

        self.app["websockets"].remove(ws)
        return ws

    async def do_websocket(self, ws: web.WebSocketResponse):
        async for ws_msg in ws:  # type: aiohttp.WSMessage
            pass

    def broadcast_message(self, msg: dict):
        for ws in self.app["websockets"]:  # type: web.WebSocketResponse
            ws.send_json(msg)


class CapitalizeEchoServer(MyServer):
    """ Echoes back to client whatever they sent, but capitalized. """

    async def do_websocket(self, ws: web.WebSocketResponse):
        async for ws_msg in ws:  # type: aiohttp.WSMessage
            cap = ws_msg.data.upper()
            ws.send_str(cap)


class RandomQuoteServer(MyServer):
    """ Sends a random quote to the client every so many seconds. """
    QUOTES = ["Wherever you go, there you are.",
              "80% of all statistics are made up.",
              "If a tree falls in the woods, and no one is around to hear it, does it make a noise?"]

    def __init__(self, interval: float = 10, *kargs, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*kargs, **kwargs)
        self.interval = interval

    async def do_websocket(self, ws: web.WebSocketResponse):
        async def _regular_interval():
            while self.srv.sockets is not None:
                quote = random.choice(RandomQuoteServer.QUOTES)
                ws.send_json({"quote": quote})
                await asyncio.sleep(self.interval)

        self.loop.create_task(_regular_interval())

        await super().do_websocket(ws)  # leave client connected here indefinitely


class TimeOfDayServer(MyServer):
    """ Sends a message to all clients simultaneously about time of day. """

    async def start(self):
        await super().start()

        async def _regular_interval():
            while self.srv.sockets is not None:
                if int(time.time()) % 10 == 0:  # Only on the 10 second mark
                    timestamp = "{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}".format(datetime.datetime.now())
                    self.broadcast_message({"timestamp": timestamp})
                await asyncio.sleep(1)

        self.loop.create_task(_regular_interval())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi @rharder, I want my 100's of clients to send their base64 image to a single server that runs on the jetson-nano board. so I want to happen asynchronously. so Could you please advise Is the above code snippet is suitable for my project?

Comment: @SaddamBinSyed yes, I think you could use this.

Answer (score 3):

So I am only familiar with Socket.IO in Node but it's fairly easy to scale websockets horizontally with Socket.IO.

Sockets can come with Sessions, so each session is managed by a specific server.  This makes it easy to save state for each socket that is open, and load balance across all of your servers.

Here is SocketIO for Python:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client

Here is a really good read on how to attach sessions to a redis-store to make it even faster and load balancing across servers more manageable.

[How to share sessions with Socket.IO 1.x and Express 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532692/how-to-share-sessions-with-socket-io-1-x-and-express-4-x)

I know this doesn't answer your question about aiohttp, but hopefully this will give you a better idea about how sockets can work.

Edit:
Written in Node-

In Socket.IO this is really easy, it has a ton of functions to broadcast messages in a variety of different ways.

For your example if you would like to emit a message across to everyone in each chat-room.  Example everyone that has a socket open you can easily just write.

```
socket.broadcast.emit('WARNING', "this is a test");
```

Let's say you have rooms open you can broadcast messages only to people in that room with a simple function called `.to()`.  Example I have a room named 'BBQ':

```
socket.broadcast.to('BBQ').emit('invitation', 'Come get some food!');
```

This will message everyone in channel BBQ - Come get some food!

Edit: Edit:

This is a fantastic write for how Socket.IO works, make sure you read the second answer for the updated versions of the functions.  It is much easier to read than their documentation.

[Send response to all clients except sender (Socket.io)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender-socket-io)

As far as I know this is how it all works in the python implementation as well.  For ease of use I would certainly use it for websockets.  The aiohttp seems really powerful but either doesn't have this functionality, buried in the documentation, or written only in the code without any documentation yet.

Comment: that's not what I'm asking. Sessions can be easily managed with http://aiohttp-session.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ - I'm referring to the actual connection to the client. In other words, how can I, given an event that occurs in server A, send a message to clients that had connected to server B.

Comment: Do you want it specifically for people connected to server B even if you had server c and server d, or do you want to emit an event to all clients that might be logged in to your servers?

Comment: think of something like a chat server - if users connected to server A send a message, then I need to send that out to users in the same chat room, even if some of those users connected to server B, C, etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah ok, I could Edit my answer for this question with a Node SocketIO implementation, but I don't know if that would help you for aiohttp.  I have not ever used aiohttp or websockets for python only in Node.  I apologize.  With SocketIO it's very easy though if you want to add another library to do websockets.

Comment: ah, actually that would be of great help, since I know Node as well.

Comment: I updated my answer twice, the link is a really easy intuitive read.

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to do that! I didn't have a chance to re-check this until now.