# How does socket.io-redis deal with rooms?

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-redis

If I have multiple processes and am using socket.io-redis, when I do `io.to(room).emit(namespace, message);` is this handled seamlessly and efficiently? Or am I misunderstanding socket.io-redis's role?

Comment: From what they say http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#passing-events-between-nodes ( ... (or even everyone in a certain room) ... ), seems like. Best way to find out is to test !

Answer (score 3):

Hi in short as far as I know about this is-

```
io.to('room').emit('namespace', 'message');
```

Means, sending `message` named **'namespace'** with value **'message'** to all clients in **'room'** channel, including sender.

Detail info (found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender-socket-io))-

```
 // send to current request socket client
 socket.emit('message', "this is a test");// Hasn't changed

 // sending to all clients, include sender
 io.sockets.emit('message', "this is a test"); // Old way, still compatible
 io.emit('message', 'this is a test');// New way, works only in 1.x

 // sending to all clients except sender
 socket.broadcast.emit('message', "this is a test");// Hasn't changed

 // sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel) except sender
 socket.broadcast.to('game').emit('message', 'nice game');// Hasn't changed

 // sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel), include sender
 io.sockets.in('game').emit('message', 'cool game');// Old way, DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE
 io.in('game').emit('message', 'cool game');// New way
 io.to('game').emit('message', 'cool game');// New way, "in" or "to" are the exact same: "And then simply use to or in (they are the same) when broadcasting or emitting:" from http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

 // sending to individual socketid, socketid is like a room
 io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');// Old way, DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE
 socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');// New way
```

---

Even more can be found **[here](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)**.

---

### Basic-

**Actually the thing is your question is so sort that it is very difficult for others to understand what u exactly need.** So, I assume u need to know basic concepts behind this also. So I am adding this part also for your kind info.

The concept here with **[socket.io](http://socket.io/)** with [**Redis**](http://redis.io/) is u should manage connection with socket and store the data in redis as DB.

[**Redis**](http://redis.io/) normally used for applying a layer upon DB (or caching database) so that some data can be stored for a time interval. So between that time, if any query is needed, data will come from Redis, not from DB query.

This system is applied for [**performance tuning**](https://synametrics.com/SynametricsWebApp/WPTop10Tips.jsp) so that your system can handle a huge load at the same time.

In your case, u can cache data for a short time interval for sending the messages through **[socket.io](http://socket.io/)**.

More can be found here-

1. http://notjoshmiller.com/socket-io-rooms-and-redis/
2. http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/136/Horizontally-Scaling-Node.js-and-WebSockets-with-Redis
3. https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis/issues/98

Think this answer will surely help u.

Comment: that is the general concept of rooms in socket.io, but doesn't address the capabilities of the socket.io-redis module.

Comment: Actually the concept here with socket.io with redis is u should manage connection with socket and store the data in redis as DB