# Broadcost massage in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

When I broadcast message sender client also get notification from NodeJs here is my code, any chance why send get notification

```
socket.on('Room', function(data) {
   console.log(' Room : '+data);
   socket.broadcast.emit('Room', {'Room': 'Room'});
});
```

Comment: yes, the sender client will receive it too because he is in the same room

Comment: how can we restricted?

Comment: you can send the id of the sender and handle it in the frontend.. maybe they got better suggestion

Answer (score 1):

[Send response to all clients except sender (Socket.io)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender-socket-io)

```
// sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel) except sender
socket.broadcast.to('game').emit('message', 'nice game');
```

Comment: Yes, but be aware that there's a bug(?) with broadcast.to().emit()
<pre>
var transport = socket.broadcast.to('room');
setTimeout(function(){

 // this works, will send to all expect the socket
 socket.broadcast.to('room).emit(e, data);
 // this doesnt work. bug?
 transport.emit(e, data);
}, 
1000);
</pre>