# How to handle front-end interactivity with multiple socket connections?

Tags: sockets, socket.io, real-time, web-frontend

So I'm new to sockets and currently experimenting on an app where users (of different types) will interact with each other involving modals, popup etc..

If I have two users, AA and BB of same type and only one user of another type CC, even if it's supposed to be an activity between AA and CC only *(e.g show a modal on AA screen when CC did x)*, the modal is also showing up on BB.

How should I design/code the front-end in such a way it will perform interactions as expected between two users where it is intended?

Should I add id in every modal or elements involved and traverse DOM before showing the modal? What is the best/right way to do this?

Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! :)

```
 // sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel) except sender
 socket.broadcast.to('game').emit('message', 'nice game');

// sending to individual socketid
socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');
```

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10099325/2098493