# Node.js Socket.io socket.brodcast is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

`brodcast.emit` to send a message to all without socket, and when I do that the node instance crashes and says that socket.brodcast is undefined .

here is my node code:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.use(express.static('public'));

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on("newChild",childData =>{
        var newChildID = mainData.newChild(childData.fatherID,childData.data, childData.type);
        socket.emit("newChildID",{ "newId" : newChildID,"old" : childData.localID});
        socket.brodcast.emit("newChild",maindata.getDataPoint(newChildID));
     });
 });
```

when I emit "newChild" from the client the server crashes and say that socket.brodcast is undefined

The important part is to get socket.brodcast.emit , so do I use the API wrong?
 when I googled after it I found this: [Send response to all clients except sender (Socket.io)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender-socket-io)

In this thread I found this example:

```
socket.on('cursor', function(data) {
   socket.broadcast.emit('msg', data);
});
```

And its seams to be the same as i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code contains a typo for starters...

```
socket.brodcast.emit("newChild",maindata.getDataPoint(newChildID));
```

should be

```
socket.broadcast.emit("newChild",maindata.getDataPoint(newChildID));
```