# Sockets IO broadcast issue

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a small chat application. I want to send a message to only the newest or last user to join the chatroom.
when I use:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('chat message');
```

This (broadcast) does the opposite of what I would like to accomplish. Is there a different built-in function that I can use instead of broadcast? I also tried emit without the broadcast and that sends to everyone. I would appreciate any help. Thansk.

Comment: You can create a `room` and `broadcast` the message to users which they are not in room for more information read this part of [socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#in(room:string):socket)

Comment: `socket.emit()` sends only to that particular socket.  That's how you send to one socket.  Get the right `socket` object and call `.emit()` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`socket.emit()` sends only to that particular socket. That's how you send to one socket.

So, get the desired socket object and call `socket.emit()`.

`.broadcast()`, on the other hand, sends to all the sockets if called in the `io` object or to all sockets but the current one if used with `socket.broadcast.emit()`.

Here's a pretty good summary of the various options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10099325/816620