# How the emit function of socket io works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

In the official site of socket.io i have a code example, my doubt is, the emit function will emit the event for all client or just for the client who connected in the sever? The example code:

Server (app.js):

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Client (index.html):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It's done per connection. Each connection to server essentially creates a socket object passed into the callback.

Comment: You can refer this answer for all different responses,
[Check out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender-socket-io#answer-10099325)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the emit function will emit the event for all client or just for the client who connected in the sever?

In your code example on the server:

`socket.emit(...)` will send a message only to that particular connection.

`io.emit(...)` will send a message to all currently connected clients.

Keep in mind that `io.emit()` doesn't have any magical powers, it just loops through all the current connected clients and calls `socket.emit()` for each one individually using their particular `socket` object - saving you the work of having to write that code yourself.

From the client, `socket.emit()` will send a message to the server.