# How do I send a message to all room users using WebRTC and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I'm working to send message to all room users using nodejs and webrtc.

This is my code:

**Client Side**

```
connection.socket.on('get mesg',function(data){
    alert(data);
});

mySocket.emit('get mesg', {
    rid:connection.sessionid,
    mesg : "I m here"
});
```

**Server Side**

```
socket.on('get mesg', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.to(data.rid).emit('get mesg', 'this is the message'); 
});
```

I want to send message on base of room id, but this is not working.

Comment: You may also find some useful information here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender

Comment: i have already tried, but in that article its using the room name I want to send using the room id .