# Not able to send message to specific user in Socket io

Tags: socket.io

I am using socket io for chatting but not able to send message to particular users  message is sending to all users in group but i want to send message for a single specific user

any solutions for this

[Send response to all clients except sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender/10099325#10099325)

Tried this link

socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
      userId: userId,
      companyId:  companyId,
      message: data
    });
  });

Answer (score 0):

To send to a specific user use:

```
io.to(<socketid>).emit('new message', { userId, companyId, message: data });
```

For this to work you need to know the socketID of the user you want to send the message to.

You can get the socketID in your server like this:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);
});
```