# Send to all except particular client(s)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have got a little different scenario. I will need to send to all (excluding sender) except particular client:

```
// sending to all clients except sender
socket.broadcast.emit('send');
```

Now, how would I exclude few or one client something like below?

```
socket.broadcast.except(id).emit('send')
// And/Or,
socket.broadcast.not([id,id]).emit('send')
```

I didn't see if there's except or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send response to all clients except sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender)

Comment: No. I have checked that already.

Comment: `namespace.clients(callback)` will return all user in `namespace`, then you can filter out the one(s) you don't want.