# Is there any way to send a message to everyone except the sender?

Tags: python, python-sockets

<sup>This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender) one, but that was for JavaScript whereas mine is for Python.</sup>

How do I send a message to every connected client from the server except a selected client in Python using the sockets library?

I am making a simple game, where I want to detect the first person to press a button among three clients, and then notify the other two clients that they lost while notifying the winner that they won.

Usually, to send information to a client you do (on a new thread):

```
connected_client.sendall(data)
```

To receive, you do:

```
data = socket.recv()
```

But from what I searched, I couldn't find a way to send data to every connected client except a certain client.

I thought I could get around this by creating an *'identifying name'* for each thread which ran the receiving function, but I couldn't find a good way to do this due to which I decided to search for a better option.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you're sending a broadcast message, you can attach an `ignore` tag with the identifiers of clients that should ignore the message. If a client recognise itself, then it will drop the message.

Comment: @crissal By identifiers of clients do you mean identifiers of the thread in which the receiving function is in or can you obtain a different identifier of a client?

Comment: Anything that is unique will work as identifier; btw your sender should know the various identifiers, and send to one rather than another accordingly.

Comment: What does: `first person to press a button` mean when you are talking about socket connections?

Comment: @quamrana Its the concept of the game I'm making, just to give you an idea of why I need an answer to this

Comment: Are you saying that: `press a button` gets translated to `receive a message` about pressing a button?

Comment: @crissal How do I set an identifier? (I'm new to the sockets library)

Comment: @quamrana Yes, the button press sends a message to the server.

Comment: If they're thread, you can read about [`get_ident()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident), or you can set your own unique `name`.

Comment: So, when you receive a message, you know who sent it. So now you know who to congratulate and by default the others you commiserate with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting them into a list can help. For example...

For the server side:

```
import socket
import threading

# This is where you store all of your Client IP's
client_list = []

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_ip = "yourip"
server_port = 8888
server.bind((server_ip, server_port))

def check_client(client_ip):
    while True:
        data = client_ip.recv(1024).decode()
        
        if "condition" in data:
            for ip in client_list:
                if ip != client_ip:
                    ip.send("something".encode())

def check_connection():
    server.listen()
    while True:
        client_ip, client_address = server.accept()
        client_list.append(client_ip)
        threading.Thread(target=check_client, args=(client_ip,), daemon=True).start()

check_connection()
```

So what happens is you call the `check_connection` function to check for incoming connections. After it receives one, it appends the connection inside the `client_list` variable. At the same time, it creates a thread to the current connection, `check_client`, which checks for any info being sent. If there's an info being sent by one of your clients, it checks if the `"condition"` string is inside your sent data. If so, it sends `"something"` string into all of your clients with exception to itself. Take note that when you send data, it must be in `bytes`.

For the client side:

```
import socket
import threading

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_ip = "serverip"
server_port = 8888
server.connect((server_ip, server_port))


def receive_info():
    while True:
        data = server.recv(1024).decode()

        if "something" in data:
            print("Someone already sent something")


threading.Thread(target=receive_info, daemon=True).start()

while True:
    user_input = input("Type 'condition': ")
    server.send(user_input.encode())
```

What this only does is, it sends your input into the server. If you typed `"condition"` on your input, it will send `"something"` on the other clients except you. So you need to setup 2 more clients in order to see the results.

Don't forget to set `server_ip` and `server_port`'s values!