# Signaling to a socket.io room within a namespace

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm having trouble setting up signaling for namespaced socket.io rooms in node.js.

It seems that certain methods are not available outside of the 'root' namespace.

app.js:

```
// I'll skip the server setup
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); 
var foo = require("./foo")(io.of('/foo'));
io.of('/foo').on('connection', function (socket) {
    try { foo.listen(socket); } catch(err) { console.log(err); }
});
```

foo.js:

```
module.exports = function(io){
    var signal = function(data){
        io.sockets.in('12345').emit('bar', data);
    };

    var listen = function(socket){
        socket.join('12345'); // no problem
        signal('test'); // woops!
    };
    return {listen: listen};
};
```

The problem occurs at `io.sockets.in('12345')`. The namespaced io has no `in` method:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'in'
```

Is there any way to broadcast to a namespaced room without using `socket.broadcast`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477770/socket-io-how-to-broadcast-messages-on-a-namespace

Comment: @Damodaran - unfortunately, it looks like that solution calls for `socket.broadcast` and I would like to keep this out of the individual sockets' event listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Because the variable passed as the `io` parameter to the `module.exports` of `foo.js` is already namespaced (it receives `io.of('/foo')`), there is no need to for the `sockets` in `io.sockets.in`. That `io` is already itself the sockets object.

In other words, I would just use:

```
var signal = function(data){
    io.in('12345').emit('bar', data);
};
```

... and it works perfectly.